# Does anyone know what the nitrogen gas on this telephone pole is for?

Tags: power-electronics, distribution-network

I saw this out walking. The tank had a sticker saying it is nitrogen. I followed the brown hose up to the cylinder on the what looks like a power wire. I would think it is a non-air "bath" to prevent arcing. I don't know what the cylinder is. Seems like something someone would steal, but the tank was left there in the open secured with an easily cuttable steel chain. So it must be worth it to have it there.

[image]

Comment: why do you believe that nitrogen is `non-air`?  ... do a web search to see how much nitrogen is in the air that you breathe

Comment: where exactly does the hose end up? ... are you sure that it attaches to a wire?

Comment: @jsotola. nitrogen is most definitely **not** air, only ~80%. Air also has oxygen, rather important for people.

Comment: jstola - pure nitrogen (often called "dry nitrogen") is *not* air.  Specifically, it has no oxygen, no water vapor, and no reactive / corrosive gasses.  Based on the images, my guess is that it is keeping a splice box lightly pressurized to keep out all of the above, which attack electrical connections.  BTW, many foods are packaged with nitrogen inside to inhibit spoilage.

Comment: A chain is a standard way to secure the cylinder to prevent it from falling over and injuring someone.

Comment: tomnexus: This is helpful. It makes total sense, I have even seen this but never realized why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, the [dry nitrogen is being used to flush moisture from cables](https://www.popsci.com/those-nitrogen-canisters-nyc-streets-are-keeping-your-internet-cables-cool/). "It turns out they're there to keep copper cables dry so phone and internet services can run smoothly." See also the [Answer Man](https://www.news-leader.com/story/news/local/ozarks/2017/06/16/answer-man-why-there-chemical-container-strapped-telephone-pole/396524001/).

[Pressurized nitrogen is also used to force optic cables through tubes.](https://www.sumitomoelectriclightwave.com/product/equipment-rental/) In that case, though, the cylinder would only have been used for a short while.